# HibernateTemplate Update Query

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-tools

How to use hql update query using hibernate template
thi is the hql statement "update Login set empSmartId = 48750005" +" where empPassword = 6328ef1675ddb7106eba8dc2661961d7"

using getHibernatetemplate()

Current code:

```
 public class LoginDaoImp extends HibernateDaoSupport implements LoginDao { 
public boolean resetAttempt(Login login) { 
try { login.setAttempt(0); 
getHibernateTemplate().update(login); 
return true; 
} catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); } 
return false; } 
i can save whole pojo class above code work but i want to use where condition to update only hibernateTemplate to update the data
```

Comment: Have you tried something yourself? Show your efforts, and show us what goes wrong, and we might be able to help you.

Comment: sir List l1 =getHibernateTemplate().find("from Login "); this will return all the data i want to know how to use this update Login set empSmartId = 48750005" +" where empPassword = 6328ef1675ddb7106eba8dc2661961d7"

Comment: This line of code doesn't do anything related to updating. I've down-voted because you've shown zero evidence of prior research and effort on your part.

Comment: Login login = new Login();
   String hql = "UPDATE Login set empPassword = :encr "  + 
               "WHERE empSmartId = :smartid"; earlier i used this but i want to know how to use update using hibernate template
  HttpSession session = (HttpSession) getSession(true);
  Query query = ((Session) session).createQuery(hql);
  query.setParameter("encr", encr);
  query.setParameter("smartid", smartid);
  int result = query.executeUpdate();*/

Comment: Do you get any error message, stacktrace or whatsoever when you run this code?

Comment: public class LoginDaoImp extends HibernateDaoSupport implements LoginDao {  public boolean resetAttempt(Login login) {
  try {
   login.setAttempt(0);
   getHibernateTemplate().update(login);
   return true;
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
     return false;
 }
i can save whole pojo class above code work but i want to use where condition to update only hibernateTemplate to update the data

Comment: It's better to update your question instead of adding comments.

Answer (score 0):

you would be looking something like this

```
public class LoginDaoImp extends HibernateDaoSupport implements LoginDao 
{ 
    public boolean resetAttempt(Login login) 
    { 
        try 
        { 
            // you should create method for login to retrived based on password
            //Remember getting login  by password is not correct way, Instead you you should use primary key
            //Getting persisted object of Login
            Login persisted_login = getLoginByPassword(6328ef1675ddb7106eba8dc2661961d7);

            //Setting value in persisted object of Login
            persisted_login.setEmpSmartId (48750005); 
            getHibernateTemplate().update(persisted_login); 
            return true; 
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
        return false; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is very old but, may this solution help someone else...

Here is a trick to update a record in DB.

The trick is **first fetch the required record from the DB, update the required fields using setter methods of associated POJO class & then give a call to `hibernateTemplate.save(Object entity)`** method, just like below:-

```
public void updateUser(User user, String password) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<User> results = (List<User>) hibernateTemplate
            .find("FROM User where username = ?", new Object[] { new String(user.getUsername()) });

    User userToBeUpdate = results.get(0);
    userToBeUpdate.setPassword(password);
    hibernateTemplate.save(userToBeUpdate);
}
```

This is working solution in my case.