# Hibernate Template update query

Tags: java, hibernate

How to use hql update query using hibernate template thi is the hql statement "update Login set empSmartId = 48750005" +" where empPassword = 6328ef1675ddb7106eba8dc2661961d7"

using getHibernatetemplate()

Current code:

```
public class LoginDaoImp extends HibernateDaoSupport implements LoginDao { 
    public boolean resetAttempt(Login login) { 
        try {
            login.setAttempt(0); 
            getHibernateTemplate().update(login); 
            return true; 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return false;
    }

}
```

i can save whole pojo class above code work but i want to use where condition

Comment: possible duplicate of [HibernateTemplate Update Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15986484/hibernatetemplate-update-query)

Answer (score 1):

`HibernateDaoSupport` will have a `getSession()` method which will return the hibernate session object for the **DataSource** configured. Using this `session`, you can say

```
Query updateQuery = getSession().createQuery("update Login l set l.empSmartId = :smartId where password = :password")
                   .setParameter("smartId", 48750005)
                   .setParameter("password", "6328ef1675ddb7106eba8dc2661961d7");
int noOfUpdatedRows = updateQuery.executeUpdate();
```